# button to disappear on-submit

Tags: android, onsubmit

In my android application, there is one submit button. On click it asks to sendData(). Before calling sendData() have put the code for disappearing the submit button and after the last routing of sendData() added code for re-appearing.

Problem: It is not working.

Code at Submit button:

```
    final FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
    if (checkValidation())
       fab.setEnabled(false);
       fab.setClickable(false);
       fab.setVisibility(fab.INVISIBLE);
       sendData();
    }
```

Code at sendData() last routine:

```
     sendEmail();
     FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
     fab.setEnabled(true);
     fab.setClickable(true);
     View b = findViewById(R.id.fab);
     b.setVisibility(b.VISIBLE);
```

Any suggestions please?

Comment: try  `floatingActionButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, "It is not working" is a vague word in this kind of scenarios.It is unclear what you are trying to achieve here.You need to make sure few things.

1. Did you place your debug pointer before and after calling sendData()?
2. Is it calling sendData() at all?
3. If it is calling sendData(), did you try removing the visibility part before calling the sendData() method?
4. If the sendData() is getting called, is it possible to remove the visibility after calling sendData() based on your requirement?
5. Did you try visibility = Gone instead of making it invisible?

These are some sample debugging steps which might or might not be suitable in your case.Please try these steps first to make sure what is wrong in your code. Hopefully, it will help you to identify the problem, then we can find out the solution.